# Custom vue component not updating on value change

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a codepen at https://codepen.io/james-hudson3010/pen/QWgarbr which demonstrates the problem.

I am trying to create and use a custom checkbox component based on using v-btn and v-icon.

When I click on the checkbox, I get the input event and the data changes, but the look of the checkbox does not change. I am certain it is because the method I call to obtain the value is not "reactive". Therefore, upon a value change, there is not a rerender.

I need to call a method to obtain the value because obtaining the value can be complex and based upon which box was clicked. There is an unknown number of boxes.

However, there is some fundamental concept I a missing here, but I am not sure what it is.

What do I need to change in my code for this to work?

(no, I do not want to use v-checkbox...in part, this is for my own edification for how to create such things.)

Javascript

```
Vue.component('mybox', {
    props: ['value'],

    data() {
      return  {
        selected: null,
      }
    },
  
    template: `
        <v-btn v-if="value" @click="clicked()" icon dense>
          <v-icon color="#f9a602">check_box</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
        <v-btn v-else @click="clicked()" icon dense>
          <v-icon color="#f9a602">check_box_outline_blank</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
    `,

    methods: {
      clicked() {
        console.log( "clicked", this.selected, this.value );
        this.selected = !this.value;
        console.log( "clicked", this.selected, this.value );
        this.$emit( "input", this.selected );
      }
    },

    watch: {
      selected() {
        console.log("selected:", this.selected);
        // this.$emit("input", this.selected);
      },
  }
});


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  
  data: {
    boxvalues: [true, false],
  },
  
  methods: {
    boxValueChanged( index ) {
      console.log( "boxValueChanged", index, this.boxvalues[ index ] );
      this.boxvalues[ index ] = !this.boxvalues[ index ];
      console.log( "boxValueChanged", index, this.boxvalues[ index ] );
    },
    
    boxValue( index ) {
      return this.boxvalues[ index ];
    }
  },
})
```

HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <mybox v-for="(value, index ) in boxvalues" 
         :value="boxValue( index )" 
         @input="boxValueChanged( index )"
         :key="index"
         :id="index"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right on track, the culprit is the loss of reactivity in this line:

```
this.boxvalues[index] = !this.boxvalues[ index ];
```

From the docs:

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> When you directly set an item with the index, e.g.
> vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue
>
> When you modify the length of the
> array, e.g. vm.items.length = newLength

There is a simple solution provided by Vue for this use cases: `Vue.set()` (or `this.$set()`) method:

```
this.$set(this.boxvalues, index, !this.boxvalues[index]);
```

You can read more on this subject [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays)

Answer (score 0):

To add to what Igor said, you can also rewrite the whole array to trigger the reactivity.
ex:

```
boxValueChanged( index ) {
  const boxvalues = [...this.boxvalues]
  
  boxvalues[index] = !boxvalues[index]
  this.boxvalues = boxvalues
},
```